# Can i use articles info for custom html modules?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

i want to create a picture sldier module, that displays the latest news article info in slider page, creating the animations and text position would be easy, but how can i get title and preview text in joomla 2.5? I want it to take info from latest 3 news articles.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR3jA.jpg

Comment: well right now looking at creating php code in templates/my_template/html/mod_custom/default.php, looking for a way to see if use custom module with title that matches that news slider module name, and gets info from newest articles and posts it, afterwards ill do css,js. Right now i just need to find a way to get info. But ill need to get info from a specific category of articles.

Comment: Don't change `templates/my_template/html/mod_custom/default.php` as this overrides the template. You need to create a module of your own. You can use the [Module Generator](http://joomjunk.co.uk/extras/module-generator.html) to get you started, and from then on, have a look at the Joomla documentation and other modules to get an idea of how data from the database is retrieved.

Comment: Thanks for placing me on the right track, now im on my own. :D

Comment: good luck with it. Once you have started coding and find yourself in a sticky situation, post another question ;)